# Getting error 438 in a VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following sub in Excel

```
Sub MapEditor()
Dim title As String
Dim tx, ty As Integer
Dim wall As String
Dim wx, wy As Integer
Dim fa As String
Dim fax, fay As Integer
Dim ora As String
Dim orax, oray As Integer
Dim datax, datay As Integer
Dim datacolumn, datarow As Integer
datacolumn = ActiveCell.Column
datarow = ActiveCell.Row
Dim dwidth As Integer, dheight As Integer
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Do While Sheets("BaseDataFightMap").Cells(1, i) <> ""
    Select Case Sheets("BaseDataFightMap").Cells(1, i).Variant
     Case Is = "width"
       dwidth = Sheets("BaseDataFightMap").Cells(Row, i).Value
     Case Is = "height"
        dheight = Sheets("BaseDataFightMap").Cells(Row, i).Value
    End Select
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

But it's giving me an error 438, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should be aware that every time you've declared two variables at once (e.g., "`Dim fax, fay As Integer`"), *only the second is the type you intend*. The first one is Variant. To get the result that I think you intend, you need: `Dim fax As Integer, fay As Integer`.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the `Case` statements from:

```
Case Is = "width"
```

to:

```
Case "width"
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such cell property as variant

```
 Sheets("BaseDataFightMap").Cells(1, i).Variant
```

Are you checking the VALUE of cell(1,i)?

```
Sheets("BaseDataFightMap").Cells(1, i).Value?
```

Also, in your code the variable Row isn't dimensioned or allocated so these 2 lines will not work yet.

```
dwidth = Sheets("BaseDataFightMap").Cells(Row, i).Value
dheight = Sheets("BaseDataFightMap").Cells(Row, i).Value
```